# Solving two parametric ODEs and then plotting a curve derived from the solutions with respect to the parameter

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have the following code

```
ClearAll {a, b, c, x, y, z, t};
X[t_] = a Cos[t];
Y[t_] = Sin[t];
sols = {NDSolve[{D[{u[t], v[t]}, t] == 
 D[{{X[t], Y[t]}, {Y[t], -X[t]}}, t].{u[t], v[t]}, {u[0], 
  v[0]} == {1, 0}}, {u, v}, {t, 0, 10}],
NDSolve[{D[{u[t], v[t]}, t] == 
 D[{{X[t], Y[t]}, {Y[t], -X[t]}}, t].{u[t], v[t]}, {u[0], 
  v[0]} == {0, 1}}, {u, v}, {t, 0, 10}]};

Print[Tr[{u[t], v[t]} /. sols]/. t -> 2 \[Pi]]
```

What I want to do is that I want to run a loop for values of $a$ (as mentioned in the second line of code), and plot the values of Tr[{u[t], v[t]} (as mentioned in the last line of code) against various values of a. Then I want to put a curve of best fit on those plot points. How do I do that? Thanks

Comment: Write a function that returns `Tr[{u[t], v[t]}]` given `a` and then generate the solutions for the desired values of `a` using `Table`. Finally, pass that to `ListPlot`. Then look at the documentation for `FindFit` (you may also want to check out the other functions referenced in that documentation.)

Comment: BTW, `ClearAll {a, b, c, x, y, z, t};` is not semantically valid and accomplishes nothing.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, an easier way to go about making the plot you want is to use `ParametricNDSolveValue`. I also suggest solving the ODEs separately. Like so:

```
X[t_] = a Cos[t];
Y[t_] = Sin[t];

uvf1 =
  ParametricNDSolveValue[
    {D[{u[t], v[t]}, t] == D[{{X[t], Y[t]}, {Y[t], -X[t]}}, t].{u[t], v[t]},
     {u[0], v[0]} == {1, 0}},
    {u[t], v[t]}, {t, 0, 10}, a];
tr1[a_, tt_] := {a, Tr @ uvf1[a] /. t -> tt}

uvf2 =
  ParametricNDSolveValue[
    {D[{u[t], v[t]}, t] == D[{{X[t], Y[t]}, {Y[t], -X[t]}}, t].{u[t], v[t]},
     {u[0], v[0]} == {0, 1}},
    {u[t], v[t]}, {t, 0, 10}, a];
tr2[a_, tt_] := {a, Tr @ uvf2[a] /. t -> tt}
```

Then to make a plot at a given value of `t`, say `t = 9`, use `ListLinePlot`:

```
With[{t = 9},
  ListLinePlot[{tr1[#, t], tr2[#, t]} & /@ Range[1, 5, .1] // Transpose,
    PlotLabel -> Row[{" Traces at t = ", t}],
    ImageSize -> Large]]
```

[image: plot]

Note: at low values of `t`, the two trace curves are essentially indistinguishable.

Answer (score 0):

If just as the author wants, then the code is

```
lst = Table[
   X[t_] = a Cos[t];
   Y[t_] = Sin[t];
   sols = {NDSolve[{D[{u[t], v[t]}, t] == 
        D[{{X[t], Y[t]}, {Y[t], -X[t]}}, t].{u[t], v[t]}, {u[0], 
         v[0]} == {1, 0}}, {u, v}, {t, 0, 10}], 
     NDSolve[{D[{u[t], v[t]}, t] == 
        D[{{X[t], Y[t]}, {Y[t], -X[t]}}, t].{u[t], v[t]}, {u[0], 
         v[0]} == {0, 1}}, {u, v}, {t, 0, 10}]}; {a, 
    Tr[{u[t], v[t]} /. sols] /. t -> 2 \[Pi]}, {a, 0, 1, .01}];

ListPlot[lst, AxesLabel -> {"a", "Tr[{u[t],v[t]}]"}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

You can select the curve of best fit using

```
FindFormula[lst, a]

(*Out[]= 0.999995 - 49.9337 a^2. - 0.14361 a^2.9619 - 43.8323 a^4. - 
 4.55363 a^5. - 6.57745 a^6. - 14.5978 a^7. + 7.7987 a^8. - 
 4.54467 a^9.*)
```